# How to resolve unused parentheses warnings in an external crate?

Tags: rust

`cargo build` is throwing warnings about unused parentheses in an external crate. I'd like to either

1. send a PR to that crate to actually fix them or
2. disable the warnings.

I can't figure out how to use the `external-macro-backtrace` flag to pinpoint exactly what this warning is complaining about. The macros in play come from the `der_parser` crate.

```
  --> src/private_key.rs:24:11
   |
24 |       match parse_der_sequence_defined!(
   |  ___________^
25 | |         input,
26 | |         parse_der_integer, // version
27 | |         parse_der_integer, // p
...  |
31 | |         parse_der_integer, // private_key
32 | |     ) {
   | |_____^ help: remove these parentheses
   |
   = note: #[warn(unused_parens)] on by default
   = note: this error originates in a macro outside of the current crate (in Nightly builds, run with -Z external-macro-backtrace for more info)
```

Note these warnings are printed on every build and my actual errors are a mile above them.

I am using

- rustc 1.25.0-nightly (616b66dca 2018-02-02)
- cargo 0.26.0-nightly (1d6dfea44 2018-01-26)

Comment: Congrats on reaching 100k :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrading to `cargo 0.26.0-nightly (1d6dfea44 2018-01-26)` and `rustc 1.25.0-nightly (3ec5a99aa 2018-02-14)` seems to have removed these warnings.